# How to delete words before and after a specific word inside a string, using R?

Tags: r, gsub

I have the following df:

```
structure(list(id = c(9L, 10L, 11L, 96L, 97L, 101L, 103L, 248L, 
499L, 1044L), leg_activity = c("home, adpt, shop, car_passenger, home, adpt, work, adpt, home pt,, work pt,, outside, outside, outside pt,, outside pt,, pt, home", 
"home pt,, pt, outside, outside, outside, outside pt,, pt, home, car, leisure, car, other, car, leisure, car, leisure, car, other, car, leisure, car, other, car, leisure, car, home, adpt, leisure, adpt, home", 
"home pt,, work, adpt, home", "home, car, work, car, home pt,, work, adpt, home", 
"home, adpt, work, car_passenger, leisure, car_passenger, work, adpt, home, car_passenger, outside, outside, outside, car_passenger, outside, outside, outside, car_passenger, home", 
"home, bike, outside, outside, outside, car_passenger, outside, outside, outside, car_passenger, outside, outside, outside, bike, home, adpt, leisure, adpt, home, bike, leisure, bike, home", 
"home, adpt, work, adpt, home, walk, other, pt, home", "home, adpt, work, walk, home, adpt, work, walk, home", 
"home, adpt, leisure, adpt, home, bike, outside, outside, outside, bike, home", 
"home, pt, work, adpt, home, adpt, work, adpt, home")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

As you can see, the `leg_activity` column contains strings. What I want is to delete all the words, which are in a connection with the word `outside`.

To be a bit more specific, lets take hypothetical row as an example:

```
"home, bike, outside, outside, outside, car_passenger, outside, outside,  bike, home, adpt, bike, leisure, bike, home"
```

The goal is to delete the word that comes before `outside` as well as the one after `outside` and eventually, `outside`ought to be deleted too. The desired output:

```
"home, home, adpt, bike, leisure, bike, home"
```

So far I'm only able to delete the specific word

```
agents$leg_activity <- gsub(', home', '', agents$leg_activity)
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can split the string on a comma, get the position of where `"outside"` is present using `grep` and remove the values before and after it.

```
agents$new_col <- sapply(strsplit(agents$leg_activity, ',{1,}\\s'), function(x) {
              inds <-  grep('outside', x)
              if(length(inds)) toString(x[-unique(c(inds - 1, inds, inds + 1))])
              else toString(x)
})
agents$new_col

# [1] "home, adpt, shop, car_passenger, home, adpt, work, adpt, home pt, home"                                                                                       
# [2] "home pt, home, car, leisure, car, other, car, leisure, car, leisure, car, other, car, leisure, car, other, car, leisure, car, home, adpt, leisure, adpt, home"
# [3] "home pt, work, adpt, home"                                                                                                                                    
# [4] "home, car, work, car, home pt, work, adpt, home"                                                                                                              
# [5] "home, adpt, work, car_passenger, leisure, car_passenger, work, adpt, home, home"                                                                              
# [6] "home, home, adpt, leisure, adpt, home, bike, leisure, bike, home"                                                                                             
# [7] "home, adpt, work, adpt, home, walk, other, pt, home"                                                                                                          
# [8] "home, adpt, work, walk, home, adpt, work, walk, home"                                                                                                         
# [9] "home, adpt, leisure, adpt, home, home"                                                                                                                        
#[10] "home, pt, work, adpt, home, adpt, work, adpt, home"
```